# How to prepend a zero in front of any number below 10 in Javascript using Regexp

Tags: javascript, regex, date

Good day,

Is there a Regex that I could use to prepend a 0 before any number that is below 10?

I am not looking for a date parsing library, ternary or if/else solutions. (hopefully)

```
var currentDate = new Date(),
    stringDate = currentDate.getFullYear() + "-" + currentDate.getMonth() + "-" + currentDate.getDate() + " " + currentDate.getHours() + ":" + currentDate.getMinutes() + ":" + currentDate.getSeconds();

    alert( stringDate ); //2011-10-17 10:3:7
```

I would like a RegExp that I could apply to stringDate to get 2011-10-17 10:03:07

Thank you very much!

Comment: don't forget to add 1 to month

Comment: @Jonas H, +1 I haven't even noticed that. Weird Date object.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Just add the leading 0 every time, then use `slice(-2)` to get the last two characters, like so:

```
('0' + currentDate.getHours()).slice(-2)
```

Comment: That is not a regex solution but it's working! And it's much cleaner then a ternary solution.

Comment: This is great and it's also easily customizable for use with any number of leading zeros (or any other character for that matter). Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

The following function will allow you to declare a minimum length for a number along or within a string and will pad it with zeros to make it the appropriate length.

```
var PrependZeros = function (str, len, seperator) {
    if(typeof str === 'number' || Number(str)){
        str = str.toString();
        return (len - str.length > 0) ? new Array(len + 1 - str.length).join('0') + str: str;
    }
    else{
        for(var i = 0,spl = str.split(seperator || ' '); i < spl.length; spl[i] = (Number(spl[i])&& spl[i].length < len)?PrependZeros(spl[i],len):spl[i],str = (i == spl.length -1)?spl.join(seperator || ' '):str,i++);
        return str;
    }
};
```

For those wanting a less cryptic version

```
var PrependZeros = function (str, len, seperator) {
    if (typeof str === 'number' || Number(str)) {
        str = str.toString();
        return (len - str.length > 0) ? new Array(len + 1 - str.length).join('0') + str : str;
    }
    else {
        var spl = str.split(seperator || ' ')
        for (var i = 0 ; i < spl.length; i++) {
            if (Number(spl[i]) && spl[i].length < len) {
                spl[i] = PrependZeros(spl[i], len)
            }
        }
        return spl.join(seperator || ' ');
    }
};
```

Examples:

```
PrependZeros("1:2:3",2,":"); // "01:02:03"
PrependZeros(1,2); // "01"
PrependZeros(123,2); // "123"
PrependZeros("1 2 3",3); // "001 002 003" 
PrependZeros("5-10-2012",2,"-"); //"05-10-2012"
```

Comment: I updated my response to have a version without the evil evil loop... I rarely write code that cryptic.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need regex for that. You can make a simple pad function yourself:

```
function pad(n) {
    if (n < 10)
        return "0" + n;
    return n;
}

alert(pad(8));
alert(pad(11));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DwnNG/

Comment: shorter: `return n<10 ? "0" + n : n;`

Answer (score 2):

I now this is old, but I just saw this simple and clean solution used on the [w3c](http://www.w3.org/TR/components-intro/) and just had to share it somewhere.

```
var hours = currentDate.getHours();
(hours < 10 ? '0' : '') + hours;
```

Comment: @tremor that's weird what version of firefox are you using? The ternary operator is widely supported across all browsers. see here at the mozilla official docs https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator#compat-desktop.

Comment: p.s. I just ran it with no problems in firefox.

Comment: The ternary operator is not in question. I made a mistake in my code, your solution is adequate, in my use of it, it was still failing to prepend the 0 but I got it working now. I'll fix my downvote, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
x.replace(/^(\d)$/, "0$1");
```

Comment: `'2011-10-17 10:3:7'.replace(/^(\d)$/, "0$1") == '2011-10-17 10:03:07'`

Comment: @Cybrix: change `x` by `currentDate.getHours()` and so on

Answer (score 1):

I prefer Alex's way, but if you **really** want the regex way, you can try:

```
   "2011-10-10 10:2:27".replace(/:(?=[^0](?::|$))/g, ":0");
```

Comment: That almost works. Working with numbers below 10 but otherwise: `2011-10-17 10:049:037`

Comment: @Cybrix how about the new one?

Answer (score 0):

That should do the work (it has an ternary operator in it, but also an regex^^)

```
stringDate.replace(/\d+/g, function(m) {
    return parseInt(m, 10) < 10 ? "0" + m : m;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you ready for your one-liner do-it-all regex solution?

Pass in your entire string... and this will match single-digits and pad them with a 0.

```
"2011-10-17 10:3:7"
.replace(/(^|[^0-9])([0-9])(?=($|[^0-9]))/ig, function ($0, $1) { 
   return $0[0] + '0' + $0[1]; 
});

//returns "2011-10-17 10:03:07"
```

This would be made so much easier if JavaScript supported lookbehind-assertions.

Answer (score 0):

%0{length} => %05 =>  1=00001, 2=00002,... 55=00055,...